# onNotify ble android never called what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to read records data from glucometer. That characteristic is not able to read or write, only set notifications. Iuse writeDescriptor and it's return true but there is no any onCharacteristicChanged callbacks

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.w("BLE", "onServicesDiscovered ")
                val service = gatt.getService(GLUCOSE_SERVICE)
                val characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(RECORDS_CHARACTERISTIC)
                gatt!!.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)
                val descriptor = characteristic!!.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)
                descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
                gatt!!.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please use a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to verify that your glucometer is indeed sending notifications

Comment: I've checked my device, so I can only indicate Record Access Control Point but I already use ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE so I don't see there anything that might be problem.

Comment: So you receive notifications (or indications) from the device using nRF Connect? I just want to make sure that the problem is not actually with your device and not with your app

Comment: I guess... Yes, I received some indications after I wrote value to Record Access Control Point right inside nRF Connect app. But when I want to `writeCharacteristic` inside my app I get false. I'm not sure why nRF Connect has write property when I haven't. Or I just didn't realize what WRITE property in nRF Connect means

Comment: In nRF Connect I choose two bytes of data to write and only then I get Indications. Should I write another desciptor in this case?

Comment: This entirely depends on your device. It might only accept a maximum of two bytes. Hard to say without a documentation

Comment: Thank you so much! With nFR Connect I found out that I must call `writeCharacteristic` with bytes of needed data in `onDescriptorWrite` method. So now I receive Notifications

Comment: I faced another problem, I didn't checked that it calls onCharacteristicWrite not onCharacteristicChanged....

Comment: Did you open a new question?

Comment: No, I found a solution, so now everything works as I expect. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe answer your own question to provide help for others facing the same problem in the future :)

Comment: Sure, I'll write it soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with Michael Kotzjan's help I found out an answer on my quiestion. First of all I've checked which glucose characteristic must turn on indications/notifications in nRF Connect app and after that just setNotification&writeDescriptor to them one by one in onDescriptorWrite method. That's sample of code, you can upgrade it because I'm sure that it can be much better

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                val charGM =
                    gatt.getService(GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_SERVICE)
                        .getCharacteristic(GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_CHARACTERISTIC)
                gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(charGM, true)

                val descGM =
                    charGM.getDescriptor(GlucometerUuids.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)
                descGM.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                gatt.writeDescriptor(descGM)
            }
        }

override fun onDescriptorWrite(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
            descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor?,
            status: Int
        ) {
            val parentCharacteristic = descriptor?.characteristic
            if(status!= BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            }
            else {
                if (parentCharacteristic?.uuid == GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_CHARACTERISTIC) {
                    val charContextGM =
                        gatt?.getService(GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_SERVICE)
                            ?.getCharacteristic(GlucometerUuids.CONTEXT_CHARACTERISTIC)
                    gatt?.setCharacteristicNotification(charContextGM, true)

                    val descContextGM =
                        charContextGM?.getDescriptor(GlucometerUuids.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)
                    descContextGM?.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                    gatt?.writeDescriptor(descContextGM)
                } else if (parentCharacteristic?.uuid == GlucometerUuids.CONTEXT_CHARACTERISTIC) {
                    val charRACP =
                        gatt?.getService(GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_SERVICE)
                            ?.getCharacteristic(GlucometerUuids.RECORDS_CHARACTERISTIC)
                    gatt?.setCharacteristicNotification(charRACP, true)
                    val descRACP =
                        charRACP?.getDescriptor(GlucometerUuids.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)
                    descRACP?.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
                    gatt?.writeDescriptor(descRACP)
                } else if (parentCharacteristic?.uuid == GlucometerUuids.RECORDS_CHARACTERISTIC) {
                    val writeRACPchar =
                        gatt!!.getService(GlucometerUuids.GLUCOSE_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(GlucometerUuids.RECORDS_CHARACTERISTIC)
                    val data = ByteArray(2)
                    data[0] = 0x01 // Report Stored records

                    data[1] = 0x01 // 0x01 - all records, 0x06 - last record, 0x05 first record 

                    writeRACPchar.value = data
                    gatt.writeCharacteristic(writeRACPchar)
                }
            }
        }
```

that code works for receive Contour One Plus glucometer data, but for other glucometers code may be a bit different. For example in Accucheck Instant there is no Context Characteristic but an algorithm is same. Glucometers data received in onCharacteristicChanged as byte array. Some glucometers are not have glucose service (for example Onetouch Select Plus Flex has own service and characteristic and this code will not work for it, unfortunately)